# prepare statement give error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

is there something wrong with my code, it look exactly like the example on the php page but it give me this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/videosharing/index.php on line 68`

```
$hi = 'hi';
$limit = 4;
$isi = 1;
$query = "SELECT `videoname`,`username`,`videourl`,`uploaddate`,`duration`,`views`,`tags` FROM `videolist` WHERE `tags` = :atagz ";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':atagz',$hi);
```

Comment: Is your connection good?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941089/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bindparam)

Comment: connection is good i didnt have any problem using standard method

Comment: Show us where you're initiating the $connection object; 99% sure that your error is there.

Comment: $connection is from db.php    require('db.php'); then i add global $connection; inside the db.php = $connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','videosharingdatabase');

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is likely fine (otherwise, you'd have a different error, sooner).

If the error is `"Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object"`, then `$stmt` isn't an object. In other words, your `prepare()` call is failing. Per [the documentation for `prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), that occurs when the database can't prepare the statement.

Reporting these errors is one of the areas where I think PDO falls short. You can get more information on the error with the following:

```
var_dump($connection->errorInfo());
```

The most likely cause is a misspelling in an attribute or table name.